# window.MapboxDirections is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mapbox, mapbox-gl

**update 2:
any idea how to achieve**

```
*but it would be great if someone could create and publish type definitions for mapbox-gl-directions to @types/mapbox__mapbox-gl-directions registry.*
```

For poc purpose I tried to install this package mapbox-gl-directions, but I am facing below error.  In the stackblitz its working in js file, even in our codebase its working fine in js file but not in tsx file. Can you let me know how to fix it ,Providing code below. Even I tried installing types also but still not working

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-mapbox-ce8v3l?file=index.tsx

```
`componentDidMount() {
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: this.mapContainer,
      style: 'mapbox://styles/bocko/ck1ayjvgx02141cmkiobyyawu',
      // center: [this.state.lng, this.state.lat],
      // zoom: this.state.zoom,
      bounds: [18.8, 42.2, 23.0, 46.2],
      maxBounds: [17, 41, 24, 47],
    });

    map.addControl(
      window.MapboxDirections({
        accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
      }),
      'top-left'
    );`
```

**Update:**

I am able to achieve by changing windows.MapboxDirections to new MapboxDirections

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-mapbox-aadezg?file=index.tsx

but because of the below issue. its not working in the codebase

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions/issues/300

```
Issues checking in progress...
ERROR in src/screens/components/Navigation.tsx:9:30
TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions'. '/Users/test-app/node_modules/@mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions/src/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/mapbox__mapbox-gl-directions` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions';`
     8 | import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css';
  >  9 | import MapboxDirections from '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions';

  yarn add --dev @types/mapbox__mapbox-gl-directions
       |

                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```